# On the incompatibility of the tikz and fp packages: division (/) operator in \FPeval and node in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, fp

Let us assume that we want to divide two numbers u=-60 and v=3 using the fp package without calling tikz picture. It works fine as below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\begin{document}
\edef\u{-60}
\edef\v{3}
\FPeval \wd{u/v}
$u/v=\wd$
\end{document}
```

The correct answer will be seen at the end:

[image]
Now let us call tikz library to put the answer in a node feature as below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\edef\u{-60}
\edef\v{3}
\FPeval \wd{u/v}
$u/v=\wd$
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at ( 0,0) {$u/v=\wd$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately we get an error in this case:

> ! You can't use `the character -' after \the.
> \wd ->-
> 20.000000000000000000
> l.11 \node at ( 0,0) {$u/v=\wd$};

- Do you know how to use node in tikz with div (`\`) of `\FPeval` at the same time?

Comment: You're overwriting the `\wd` primitive.  This calls for trouble.  Name your macro `\mywd` or so instead.

Comment: Same goes for the `\u` and `\v` single letter macros.  There are use for diacritics.  In general, *thou shalt not redefine single letter macros*.

Comment: Thanks @Henri, When I use `\w` instead of `\wd` for the variable name it works with tikz.

Comment: Did you not read my second comment?

Comment: I did but did not understand well. Would you please explain in other way?

Comment: Do not (re)define macros, whose name is only a single character.

Comment: Aha. So u and v are not good variable names because they are single characters? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  To be on the safe side just always use a unique prefix, e.g. `\ariau` and `\ariav`.  These are highly unlikely to be defined by any other package and should therefore always be safe to use.

Comment: Also use `\newcommand` instead of `\def`.  The former will throw an error if the macro you are trying to define already exists.

Comment: Thanks @Henri in the fp package they use single character x as a variable that’s why I thought single character variables are allowed.

Comment: why do you use fp instead of e.g. xfp or the math library of pgf?

Comment: Because I am new, thanks for your suggestion. Do you know how to get access to the math library in TikZ?

Comment: you can find a description in the pgfmanual. And a comparision of the three calculation methods is here  https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb40-1/tb124wright-fpkg.pdf (a shorter version is here https://www.texdev.net/2018/12/09/floating-point-calculations-in-latex)

Comment: @ Ulrike: thanks! It seems the xfp is the right tool. Fast and accurate according to the 2nd article u shared. Do u agree?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's quite unfortunate that `fp` doesn't offer an option to warn the user when the first argument to an `\FP...` macro is already defined.

It's also (unfortunate) common practice to use short names for variables to use in Ti*k*Z. This may have no side effect if used inside a `tikzpicture`, because (non global) redefinitions are nullified when the `tikzpicture` ends.

***Not always safe***: in a very recent question, a user got into troubles because of using `\color` as the name for a variable in a `\foreach` loop, but the loop code used `\textcolor`.

In your case, you're redefining three existing control sequences:

- `\u` is for the “breve accent”, whence `\u{a}` yields ă;
- `\v` is for the “háček” accent, whence `\v{c}` yields č;
- `\wd` is a primitive TeX command that's used in several places, as it returns the width of some built box.

While the first two redefinitions are harmless in your example, because it doesn't sport accented letters, the last one is fatal. At some point, TeX is instructed to do some calculations involving the box containing the text to be typeset at the node and it needs the width of that box, which it inquires using `\wd`; but `\wd` now means something completely different.

Here is a different method. The names are longer, but the input is much clearer. With `\fpeval` you can do computations on the spot (see the second node).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp} % not fp
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setfpvar}{mm}
 {
  \fp_zero_new:c { l_aria_fpvar_#1_fp }
  \fp_set:cn { l_aria_fpvar_#1_fp } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\fpvar}{m}
 {
  \fp_use:c { l_aria_fpvar_#1_fp }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\setfpvar{u}{-60}
\setfpvar{v}{3}
\setfpvar{wd}{\fpvar{u}/\fpvar{v}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {$u/v=\fpvar{wd}$};
\node at (0,-1) {$u/v=\fpeval{\fpvar{u}/\fpvar{v}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: We should remind Bruno about the ideas of having named variables in expressions: it's in `l3trial` at the moment